# Make Jekyll ignore some HTML files

Tags: jekyll, bower

I'm making a theme for Jekyll and I want to make use of some Bower components. However, when I try to build my site, Jekyll tries to process some HTML files inside the components directory. One of the components ([Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome)) uses Jekyll for its docs, and it includes a non-existent (in my case) template, then all the process fails.

My question is: is there any way to make jekyll ignore all the HTML files inside some directory and copy them as is?

Answer (score 7):

You can exclude files and folders from the conversion process by adding an `exclude` configuration option to your `_config.yml`.

This is [documented here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), under Global Configuration.

Comment: This is what I do now. However, I need to copy my files manually this way, and it's a bit inconvenient.